# Vanishing Christoffels symbols

Tags: differential-geometry

Under what conditions does there exist a parametrization of a surface, for which the Christoffel symbols are zero. I heard that has something to do with "flat connection". I would like to see proofs.

Comment: Then you should have a very special Riemannian metric I guess (it is not specified here). Besides, I only know under normal coordinate, the Christoffel symbols vanish at a point.

Comment: You need to specify your background. This sort of thing should be in a good introductory differential geometry course. Left to my own devices, I would give an explanation/proof using differential forms and structure equations, but I am not likely to spend the time to write it all when you may not know enough to understand it.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I am talking about the introductory geometry. I was thinking about saying "3D" surface, to specify what exactly I need. Do I have to post it again somewhere else!

Comment: Are you familiar with the differential forms approach to surface theory? If not, it takes some partial differential equations to prove that a flat surface is locally isometric to $\Bbb R^2$ with all Christoffel symbols $0$.